# JSP Session Variable Unavailable

Tags: jsp

I am a Perl developer working on JSP pages. All is going well except for one final problem. I am getting the following error when I refresh a page where the session has expired.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page... at line 10
```

On line 10 the code pulls the session variable which no longer exists. Is there a way to write the code so it stores a false value if the session variable does not exist.

```
boolean b_checkin = ((Boolean)session.getAttribute("session_checkin"));
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Boolean` instead. `boolean` is a primitive type and can only hold `true` or `false` values. On the other hand, [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) is a class wrapper for the `boolean` primitive type, since it holds an object it accepts `null` value too. So, you could update your code to:

```
Boolean b_checkin = (Boolean)session.getAttribute("session_checkin");
//if the session expired, then define a default value (probably false)
//otherwise, use the value obtained from session
b_checkin = (b_checkin == null) ? false : b_checkin;
```

A short-hand way to do it:

```
Boolean b_checkin = Boolean.TRUE.equals(session.getAttribute("session_checkin"));
```

Comment: Would this work ?    Boolean b_checkin = (Boolean)session.getAttribute("session_checkin")!=Boolean.FALSE;

Comment: @wall-nut IMO if it's `null` then it should be `false`. If that's the case, then just compare it with `Boolean.TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
boolean b_checkin = session.getAttribute("session_checkin")!=null;
```

If the *session_checkin* attribute is null then b_checkin is false. Otherwise true.

Comment: I will add that. I will have to wait for the session to expire to see if it works for me.

Comment: I think you cannot do Boolean cast to any data type except for booleans _true_ or _false_. Try doing a manual cast in your IDE like so: `boolean check = (Boolean)"Test string";` and it will not work.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if `session.getAttribute("session_checkin")` holds `true`, since is different than `null`, `b_checkin` value will be `false` =\

Comment: Then add another condition like so: `boolean b_checkin = (session.getAttribute("session_checkin")!=null || session.getAttribute("session_checkin")==true);`